# How to monitor all network activity on a BT HomeHub 5

Tags: router, monitoring, home-hub

I would like to be able to see all websites accessed through my home router and which device was used to access them.

I have tried to use OpenDNS but BT does not support this.

Is there a way I can enable OpenDNS or otherwise monitor my router?

If there is not, what other program can do the same job and is compatible with BT hubs?

Comment: What's wrong with the event logs on the router?

Comment: [Checking Visited Websites On Bt Router Is It Possible?](https://forums.overclockers.co.uk/threads/checking-visited-websites-on-bt-router-is-it-possible.18771529/) gives some alternatives.

Comment: Going back a few years, it wasn't possible to use alternative DNS servers if Parental Controls was active. It also wasn't possible to specify DNS servers in the HomeHub, so they had to be set in each device.